# ng test cannot start firefox

Tags: angular, windows, permissions, karma-runner

```
Windows 10 Pro
Node 10.14.1
npm 6.4.1
Angular 7.2.15
Angular CLI 7.3.9

$ npm install karma --save-dev
$ npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev

$ ng test
17 09 2019 13:08:47.472:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
17 09 2019 13:08:47.499:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.3.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
17 09 2019 13:08:47.499:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Firefox with concurrency unlimited
17 09 2019 13:08:47.512:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
17 09 2019 13:08:47.821:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Firefox

17 09 2019 13:08:47.821:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox stdout:
17 09 2019 13:08:47.821:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox stderr:
17 09 2019 13:08:53.544:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Firefox again (1/2).
17 09 2019 13:08:53.545:WARN [temp-dir]: Failed to create a temp dir at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2\karma-77822405
17 09 2019 13:08:59.446:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Firefox

17 09 2019 13:08:59.446:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox stdout:
17 09 2019 13:08:59.446:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox stderr:
17 09 2019 13:09:00.645:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
17 09 2019 13:09:02.550:INFO [Firefox 68.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket Q7q0OTZs2xJ4M7E9AAAA with id 77822405
Firefox 68.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 44 of 44 SUCCESS (0.312 secs / 0.267 secs)
TOTAL: 44 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 44 SUCCESS
17 09 2019 13:09:04.765:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Firefox again (2/2).
17 09 2019 13:09:04.766:WARN [temp-dir]: Failed to create a temp dir at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2\karma-77822405
17 09 2019 13:09:10.043:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Firefox

17 09 2019 13:09:10.043:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox stdout:
17 09 2019 13:09:10.043:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox stderr:
17 09 2019 13:09:13.175:ERROR [launcher]: Firefox failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
```

Note that I can manually open Firefox browser.

Also note that in `cmd.exe` or `git-bash.exe` I can go to this dir and create a sub-dir `temp`

Comment: Global or local install (npm install -g karma)?

Comment: When do you get the error? Immediately after running the command?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau I edited post

Comment: So I created a starter project (ng new angular-test) and yes to routing. Then I ran your commands and no problem. I use powershell run as admin. Does this work for you also?

Comment: No it does not work. I suspect something specific to my Firefox install/config. Did you fresh install Firefox in your environment ?

Comment: I don't have firefox installed. ng test launches in chrome browser.

Comment: I newly installed Firefox and I changed to this line in karma.config.js browsers: ['Firefox'], and that works, no problem.

Comment: There is also karma start --wait-for-browser BUT don't know how to do the same with the plugin. Maybe there is a corresponding config setting.